# Assign the value of shell command line's output to a Vaiable in python

Tags: python-3.x, shell, variables, subprocess

I have a file with the below contents.

```
[oracle@hostname POST_DB_REFRESH_VALIDATIONS]$ cat .DB_Creds.txt
DEW:SYSTEM:ss2021:NPDOR
STW:SYSTEM:ss2021:NPDOR
```

When i run the below command in shell I am getting exact output as SYSTEM

```
[oracle@hostname POST_DB_REFRESH_VALIDATIONS]$ grep DEW .DB_Creds.txt | awk -F':' '{print $2}'
SYSTEM
```

whereas when i run the same in python3 command line using `subprocess`, i am getting the output as below.

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Sep 26 2019, 11:57:09)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.check_output("grep DEW .DB_Creds.txt | awk '{print $2}'", shell=True)
>>> print(output)
    b'SYSTEM\n'
```

I just want it as SYSTEM, not with any other special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output` has type `bytes`. You want to first decode that to a value of type `str`, then strip the trailing newline.

```
>>> print(output.decode().strip())
SYSTEM
```

You can observe the differences made by the method calls:

```
>>> output
b'SYSTEM\n'
>>> output.decode()
'SYSTEM\n'
>>> output.decode().strip()
'SYSTEM'
```

`decode` treats the `bytes` value as the UTF-8 encoding of a string by default, but that assumption is valid since you have plain ASCII text.